# Trouble with keyinput in java on a mac

Tags: java, macos, swing, keylistener

For some reason, key inputs stop working after awhile on mac computers. I sent my project to my friends and they say it work perfectly, but key inputs break for me after a while. Is there a reason for that? It seems like it happens out of nowhere and usually happens after I move around the player. It doesn't seem like it has a pattern too. I also don't get any error messages or crash messages so I'm just really confused. Thanks for all the help :D

```
package entity;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

import main.Animation;
import main.Sprite;

public class Player {
    KeyListener keyboard;

    Animation animation;
    Animation walkRight;
    Animation walkLeft;
    Animation walkUp;
    Animation walkDown;
    Animation stand;

    Sprite sprite;
    // BufferedImage currentSprite;

    boolean walkY, walkX;

    private int scale, x, y, tick;
    private boolean right, left, up, down, middleOfRight, middleOfLeft, middleOfUp, middleOfDown;

    public Player(int scale) {
        initKeyboard();
        sprite = new Sprite("spriteSheet", 32);
        walkLeft = new Animation(sprite, 0, 2, 1, 1, 16, true);
        walkRight = new Animation(sprite, 0, 2, 2, 2, 16, true);
        walkUp = new Animation(sprite, 0, 2, 3, 3, 16, true);
        walkDown = new Animation(sprite, 0, 2, 0, 0, 16, true);
        stand = new Animation(sprite, 1, 1, 0, 0, 10000, false);
        animation = stand;
        this.scale = scale;
        x = 32;
        y = 32;
    }

    public void update() {
        animation.update();
        if (right || middleOfRight) {
            x += 2;
            if (x % 32 == 0) {
                middleOfRight = false;
                if (!right && animation != walkUp && animation != walkDown) {
                    animation = stand;
                }
            } else
                middleOfRight = true;
        } else if (left || middleOfLeft) {
            x -= 2;
            if (x % 32 == 0) {
                middleOfLeft = false;
                if (!left && animation != walkUp && animation != walkDown) {
                    animation = stand;
                }
            } else
                middleOfLeft = true;
        }
        if (up || middleOfUp) {
            y -= 2;
            if (y % 32 == 0) {
                middleOfUp = false;
                if (!up && animation != walkRight && animation != walkLeft) {
                    animation = stand;
                }
            } else
                middleOfUp = true;
        } else if (down || middleOfDown) {
            y += 2;
            if (y % 32 == 0) {
                middleOfDown = false;
                if (!down && animation != walkRight && animation != walkLeft) {
                    animation = stand;
                }
            } else
                middleOfDown = true;
        }

        tick++;
    }

    public void render(Graphics screen) {
        screen.drawImage(animation.getSprite(), x, y, 32 * scale, 32 * scale, null);
    }

    public KeyListener getKeyboard() {
        return keyboard;
    }

    private void initKeyboard() {
        keyboard = new MyKeyListener();
    }

    class MyKeyListener extends KeyAdapter {
        private boolean[] keysX = { false, false };
        private boolean[] keysY = { false, false };

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("test");
            int key = e.getKeyCode();
            switch (key) {
            // case (KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT):
            case (KeyEvent.VK_D):
                right = true;
                left = false;
                middleOfLeft = false;
                animation = walkRight;
                animation.start();
                tick = 0;
                break;
            // case (KeyEvent.VK_LEFT):
            case (KeyEvent.VK_A):
                right = false;
                left = true;
                middleOfRight = false;
                animation = walkLeft;
                animation.start();
                tick = 0;
                break;
            // case (KeyEvent.VK_DOWN):
            case (KeyEvent.VK_S):
                up = false;
                down = true;
                middleOfUp = false;
                if (animation == stand || animation == walkUp) {
                    animation = walkDown;
                    animation.start();
                }
                break;
            // case (KeyEvent.VK_UP):
            case (KeyEvent.VK_W):
                down = false;
                up = true;
                middleOfDown = false;
                if (animation == stand || animation == walkDown) {
                    animation = walkUp;
                    animation.start();
                }
                break;
            }

        }

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            int key = e.getKeyCode();

            switch (key) {
            case (KeyEvent.VK_W):
                up = false;
                break;
            case (KeyEvent.VK_S):
                down = false;

                break;
            case (KeyEvent.VK_A):
                left = false;
                if (up) {
                    animation = walkUp;
                    animation.start();
                } else if (down) {
                    animation = walkDown;
                    animation.start();
                }
                break;
            case (KeyEvent.VK_D):
                right = false;
                if (up) {
                    animation = walkUp;
                    animation.start();
                } else if (down) {
                    animation = walkDown;
                    animation.start();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void setUpInput(JFrame frame) {
        JPanel pane = (JPanel) frame.getContentPane();

        pane.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("D"), "move right");
        pane.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released D"), "release right");
        pane.getActionMap().put("move right", new MoveAction("right", false));
        pane.getActionMap().put("release right", new MoveAction("right", true));

        pane.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("A"), "move left");
        pane.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released A"), "release left");
        pane.getActionMap().put("move left", new MoveAction("left", false));
        pane.getActionMap().put("release left", new MoveAction("left", true));

        pane.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("W"), "move up");
        pane.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released W"), "release up");
        pane.getActionMap().put("move up", new MoveAction("up", false));
        pane.getActionMap().put("release up", new MoveAction("up", true));

        pane.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("S"), "move down");
        pane.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released S"), "release down");
        pane.getActionMap().put("move down", new MoveAction("down", false));
        pane.getActionMap().put("release down", new MoveAction("down", true));

    }

    private class MoveAction extends AbstractAction {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        String direction;
        boolean released;

        MoveAction(String direction, boolean released) {
            this.direction = direction;
            this.released = released;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (!released) {
                switch (direction) {
                // case (KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT):
                case ("right"):
                    right = true;
                    left = false;
                    middleOfLeft = false;
                    animation = walkRight;
                    animation.start();
                    tick = 0;
                    break;
                // case (KeyEvent.VK_LEFT):
                case ("left"):
                    right = false;
                    left = true;
                    middleOfRight = false;
                    animation = walkLeft;
                    animation.start();
                    tick = 0;
                    break;
                // case (KeyEvent.VK_DOWN):
                case ("down"):
                    up = false;
                    down = true;
                    middleOfUp = false;
                    if (animation == stand || animation == walkUp) {
                        animation = walkDown;
                        animation.start();
                    }
                    break;
                // case (KeyEvent.VK_UP):
                case ("up"):
                    down = false;
                    up = true;
                    middleOfDown = false;
                    if (animation == stand || animation == walkDown) {
                        animation = walkUp;
                        animation.start();
                    }
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                switch (direction) {
                case ("up"):
                    up = false;
                    break;
                case ("down"):
                    down = false;
                    break;
                case ("left"):
                    left = false;
                    if (up) {
                        animation = walkUp;
                        animation.start();
                    } else if (down) {
                        animation = walkDown;
                        animation.start();
                    }
                    break;
                case ("right"):
                    right = false;
                    if (up) {
                        animation = walkUp;
                        animation.start();
                    } else if (down) {
                        animation = walkDown;
                        animation.start();
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that it might be crashing  but I can't find what causes it?

Comment: Als when I tap, it seems fine?

Comment: For Swing, we typically use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than the lower level `KeyListener`.

Comment: Yes, the problem is likely that the component that has a `KeyListener` on it is losing focus. Using key bindings is easier and better in every way.

Comment: Yea, i used both, i switched to key bindings, check the bottom of the code